# How can I get specific columns from this CSV file?

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

How can I get all latitudes and longitudes values from this CSV file?

```
id   M3_id   name   adress   city              postcode   state   phone   email   url   brandstore   online   country_id   latitude                    longitude                   fax   season   filename   order   public
             bla    xxx      Biedermannsdorf   A-2362             458             www   0            0        15           4.808.707.420.000.000.000   1.635.738.590.000.000.000   4     SW                  0       1
             bla    xxx      y                 A-8053             456             www   0            0        15           470.106.506                 154.049.301                 5     SW                  0       1
     0       bla    xxx      y                 A-1200             5467            ww    0            0        15           482.283.707                 163.706.093                 8     SW                  0       1
             bla    xxxy     Linz              A-4020             665             www   0            0        15           483.092.194                 143.290.005                 7     S                   0       1
                                                                                  ww    1            1        15                                                                         SW       none       0       1
```

Code so far: But I can figure out the next step to get coordinates from the array...

```
$filepath = "uploads/austria.csv"; 
    $file_handle = fopen($filepath, "r");

    $countRows = 0; 
     while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        // get data using fgetcsv and push to an array
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        $countRows++; 
    }

    //Close the file after reading
    fclose($file_handle);

    print "<pre>"; 
    print_r($line_of_text);
    print "</pre><b>"; 


    function importDataFromCvsFile($fileName, $delimiter = ',') {
        $result = array();
        if (($handle = fopen($fileName, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 2000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
                $result[] = $data;
            }
            fclose($handle);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Start by using [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) (or its [SPLFileObject equivalent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.fgetcsv.php))with a tab separator to read each line of the file in turn into an array, then extract the columns that you want from that array

Comment: perhaps you should have started with the PHP docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Please check my code again

Comment: To start with, it looks like the delimiter in this file is a tab (`"\t"`), not the default comma (`,`)

Comment: It's comma when I open the file in notepad.

Comment: Then show us the actual csv file, not one with tabs in it